# How to make asyncio task / coroutine return values to be assigned

Tags: python, asynchronous

**TL;DR:**
I want to create asyncio task/coroutine and get the return values to be assigned in a var.

-

I found this question [Getting values from functions that run as asyncio tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456881/getting-values-from-functions-that-run-as-asyncio-tasks)
Which **seems** to talk about a similar issue, but the sintax has changed a lot in the asyncio module that I not even sure if it's related. [**I'm on Python 3.7.2**]

Sample code for me to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
async def s(f):
    func = {
        1: op1,
        2: op2,
        3: op3
      }.get(f,False)
    var = func(f)
    return var

def op1(f):
    print('Op1',f+f)
    return f+f

def op2(f):
    print('Op2', f*f)
    return f*f

def op3(f):
    print('Op3', f**f)
    return f**f

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(s(1))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(s(3))
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task1
    await task2
    print(task1,task2)
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

The main() is a example coroutine from docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines

The s() is supposed to be a switch which will select the proper function (one of op1,op2,op3) for the scenario, run the function and RETURN the result, (from what I expected) to be assigned to task1/task2.

What is actually assigned to the task1/task2 is:

```
<Task finished coro=<s() done, defined at C:\...\test.py:17> result=2> 
<Task finished coro=<s() done, defined at C:\...\test.py:17> result=27>
```

As you can see, the return is stored in 'result' (attribute? var?) but not directly assigned to the var.

I need either: Assign the return directly to the var **OR** a way to access the 'result' and assign it to a var where I can further manipulate.

BTW: `print(task1.result)` returns this:
`<built-in method result of _asyncio.Task object at 0x0000028592DDA048>`

Comment: Sounds like you need to write: `print(task1.result())`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```py
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(s(1))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(s(3))
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    result_of_task1 = await task1
    result_of_task2 = await task2
    print(result_of_task1,result_of_task2)
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

is one way to do it. I prefer this, as it makes awaiting tasks more like normal function calls, but also equivalent is

```py
await task1
# some time later
result_of_task1 = task1.result()
```

You just missed the `()`, because result is a method, not a member variable.

Comment: I was under the impression you couldn't assign await expression. Anyway, both ways solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: How can I change the above such that function `s` can return multiple values?

Comment: @AnuragAS you can simply return a tuple and receive it as a tuple, just like any other python function