# Set Async Create Task to two Variables

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm repurposing some synchronous python code to be asynchronous. It is working really well, but when I change this line of code

```
    l = asyncio.create_task(Functions.getData(session, id))
```

to this

```
    l, i = asyncio.create_task(Functions.getData(session, id))
```

I get a RuntimeError that says this.

```
"Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
await wasn't used with future
  File 'test.py', line 46, in get_tasks
    l, i = asyncio.create_task(Functions.getData(session, id))
    ^^^^
  File 'test.py', line 79, in get_data
    a, b, c = get_tasks(session)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File 'test.py', line 108, in <module>
    asyncio.run(get_data())
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future"
```

My getData function returns a tuple (var1, var2), but for some reason asyncio does not like it.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779254/how-to-make-asyncio-task-coroutine-return-values-to-be-assigned) help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you use `asyncio.create_task`, it returns a single future object representing the task. If you want to unpack multiple values from the result of `Functions.getData`, you should do it after awaiting the task.

```
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, id):
    # Simulating some asynchronous operation
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "result1", "result2"

async def get_tasks(session, id):
    task = asyncio.create_task(get_data(session, id))
    result = await task  # Wait for the task to complete
    var1, var2 = result
    return var1, var2

async def main():
    session = None  # Replace with your session
    id = 123  # Replace with your id
    var1, var2 = await get_tasks(session, id)
    print(var1, var2)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This way, you await the task and then unpack the results

Comment: Ah, that was it. Been trying to solve this one for a while. Thank you!