# Concatenate the result of multiple functions

Tags: python

I have this code that contains multiple function. The output is fine except that the result of each function appears on a different line. I actually want the output concatenated as one item. I used +, %, f', almost everything I see on the net. Please help. The code is below.

````
import string
import asyncio

async def get_random_string(length):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    print(str(result_str))

    
async def my_function1():
  print(str(random.randint(0,9)))
  
async def my_function2():
  print(str(random.randint(100,999)))
  
async def my_function3():
  print(str(random.randint(100000,999999)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(my_function1(), get_random_string(3),\
   my_function2(), get_random_string(4), my_function3()))```
````

Comment: Your functions shouldn't print their results, they should return them. Then you can combine them in any way you want.

Comment: I see the close for duplicate related to new lines in `print` but in case the `asyncio`-ness was the point of confusion here, Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456881/getting-values-from-functions-that-run-as-asyncio-tasks

Answer (score 0):

This is because `print` by default ends with a newline (\n) character.

You can override this:

```py
def print_many_lines():
    print("line 1")
    print("line 2")
    print("line 3")

def print_one_line():
    print("line 1", end=" ")
    print("line 2", end=" ")
    print("line 3")
```

You could also change your code to have the functions return `str` instead and then just collect the resulting strings and print them all at once in one line like:

```py
print(" ".join([func1(), func2(), func3()]))
```

(altho admittedly a little different for your example w/ asyncio - the idea is still the same)

For your asyncio case, your code just changes to:

```py
# change all of the functions to `return str(...)` instead of `print(...)`

results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(...)
print(" ".join(results))
```

Comment: Thanks a million. You have no idea how much this helped me.

Comment: Great! I'm curious if the reason for closing on this question was accurate - Does this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space) answer your question? Does this [asyncio specific one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456881/getting-values-from-functions-that-run-as-asyncio-tasks) answer your Q? If neither do, then maybe this question shouldn't have been closed and should instead be edited in some way and unclosed